# How to map sequence only if a condition applies with scala using an immutable approach?

Tags: scala, dictionary, if-statement, immutability

Given a sequence of `Price` objects,  I want to map it to `applyPromo` function if a condition, i.e. `promo == "FOO"` applies, otherwise return the sequence as is.

This is my applyPromo:

```
val pricePromo = price => price.copy(amount = price.amount - someDiscount)
```

In a mutable way I probably would write it like this:

```
var prices: Seq[Price] = Seq(price1, price2, ...)
  .map(doStuff)
  .map(doSomeOtherStuff)
if (promo == "FOO") {
  prices = prices.map(applyPromo)
}
prices
```

I was wondering if I could do something similar like this while keeping the immutable approach of scala. Instead of creating a temp `var`, I prefer to keep the chain.

Pseudo-code:

```
val prices = Seq(price1, price2, ...)

prices
  .map(dosStuff)
  .map(doOtherStuff)
  .mapIf(promo == "FOO", applyPromo)
```

I don't want to check the condition within the map function in this case, as it applies for all elements:

```
prices.map(price => { 
  if (promo == "FOO") {
    applyDiscount(price) 
  } else
    price
  } 
)
```

Comment: you can create a recursive function with match case and call that function instead of map. :)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use `else` to make it functional (and you can create an `implicit class` to add the `mapIf` method if you prefer):

```
val prices: Seq[Price] = Seq(price1, price2,...).map(doStuff).map(doSomeOtherStuff)
/* val resultPrices = */ if (promo == "FOO") {
  prices.map(price => {
    price.copy(amount = price.amount - someDiscount)
  })
} else prices
```

Something like this:

```
implicit class ConditionalMap[T](seq: Seq[T]) extends AnyVal {
  def mapIf[Q](cond: =>Boolean, f: T => Q): Seq[Q] = if (cond) seq.map(f) else seq
}
```

You can also `map(x => x)` in the else case:

```
val discountFunction = if (promo == "FOO") (price: Price) =>
    price.copy(amount = price.amount - someDiscount) else (x: Price) => x
val prices: Seq[Price] = Seq(price1, price2,...).
  map(doStuff).
  map(doSomeOtherStuff).
  map(discountFunction)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it like this:

```
val maybePromo: (Price => Price) = 
  if(promo == "FOO") applyPromo else identity _

prices.map(maybePromo)
```

Or you can inline it within `map` itself:

```
prices.map(if(promo == "FOO") applyPromo else identity)
```

Comment: I assume `identity` is a function that returns the same value as its input. So in this case it still would iterate over all the price elements of the sequence, wouldn't it? I know, premature optimization, yet I am looking for a way to avoid unnecessary iteration in this case.

Comment: I believe the answer referes to `Predef.identity` which returns the same value as input. When you say avoid unnecessary iteration what does that mean?? how can you know whether to apply discount or not without reading the price info? Also in your question where the heck `promo` come from? Is it one for each price or a same for all all prices?

Comment: @k0pernikus then the Gabor's answer is way to go.

Comment: (My last option is practically the same as this.) It worth noting that if you use something like `for (...; x <- expr) yield x` that will result in `.map(identity)` at the end, which might or might not be fused with other operations, but in general that is _not_ considered as an antipattern, I would say optimizing it away is probably premature optimization.

Comment: In this case it's the same rule for all prices. So one doesn't have to check the condition within the mapped function but it can be determined at runtime if it should be applied at all.

Answer (score 1):

In scalaz, a function `A => A` is called an *endomorphism* and is a **Monoid** whose associative binary operation is function composition and whose identity is the identity function. This is useful because there is a bunch of syntax available where monoids are concerned. For example, scalaz adds the `??` operation to boolean along these lines:

```
def ??[A: Monoid](a: A) = if (self) a else Monoid[A].zero
```

Thus:

```
prices
  .map(doStuff)
  .map(doSomeOtherStuff)
  .map(((promo === "FOO") ?? deductDiscount).run)
```

Where:

```
val deductDiscount: Endo[Price] = Endo(px => px.copy(amount = px.amount - someDiscount))
```

The above all requires

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
```

**Notes**

1. `===` is typesafe [equals syntax](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/e5ddd94281f2816c80249b37de3d151b87d827bf/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/syntax/EqualSyntax.scala#L5)
2. `??` is [boolean syntax](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/431f4bafee4d734c89b7f70bca9f88e92ecd4ac6/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/syntax/std/BooleanOps.scala#L242)

Answer (score 1):

[oxbow_lakes has an interesting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47508006/432903)

Easy way solve to me is wrapping `Seq` in a `Option` context.

```
scala> case class Price(amount: Double)
defined class Price
```

**when condition matches,**

```
scala> val promo = "FOO"
promo: String = FOO

scala> Some(Seq(Price(1), Price(2), Price(3))).collect{
            case prices if promo == "FOO" => prices.map { p => p.copy(p.amount - 1 )} 
            case prices => prices} 
res6: Option[Seq[Price]] = Some(List(Price(0.0), Price(1.0), Price(2.0)))
```

**when condition does not match**

```
scala> val promo = "NOT-FOO"
promo: String = NOT-FOO

scala> Some(Seq(Price(1), Price(2), Price(3))).collect{
            case prices if promo == "FOO" => prices.map { p => p.copy(p.amount - 1 )} 
            case prices => prices} 
res7: Option[Seq[Price]] = Some(List(Price(1.0), Price(2.0), Price(3.0)))
```

Comment: In this case it is always safe to extract the `Some`, something like `val Some(resultPrices) = ...`.